# Android Navigation - Finding line perpendicular to a line drawn through two locations

Tags: java, android, math, trigonometry

I have two location specified in latitude and longitude (A and B). Between these location is a line (Green). I am at a third location (Me). How do I determine how far I am away from this line and in what direction the closest point to it is from where I am (the Gray line)?

I'm looking for heading in degrees and distance in meters. If I can find the location at which the gray line meets the green line then I can use the Android Location built in functions to calculate distance and heading.

Does anybody know given the lat/long locations of A, B and Me how to solve the above problem?

Bear in mind that 'Me' does not know whether he's in the first or second situation and that this is a navigation problem.

Also I would appreciate it if you would also bear in mind that I'm crap at maths and answer like your talking with a 15 year old.

Also, I've worked out an example by hand using Google Earth. So given:

```
double aLat = 51.44376;
double aLng = -2.86525;

double bLat = 51.43574;
double bLng = -2.87026;

double meLat = 51.4391;
double meLng = -2.86437;

Answer should be:
Distance to closest point on line (aprox): 235 meters
Heading to closest point on line (aprox): 109 degrees
```

As always, thanks for your help,

Adam

[image]

Comment: I only made a quick search. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120357/get-closest-point-to-a-line

Comment: Not really, it only works with cartesian products not with lat/long.

Comment: I think you can rework your problem to cartesian representation.

Comment: what do you mean by aprox in the above? How do you obtain the number 235?

Comment: Here is a link with how to do this http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: @Noan Nguyen, Like I said the the question, I worked through it on Google Earth so the results will only be proximate. If you put the lat/lng figures in Google maps you will see where the points were and what I was doing.