# TSQL - get closest coordinate on linestring to a point

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gis

Consider the overly simplistic example: POINT(0 0) and LINESTRING (1 -10, 1 10)

The closest point on the line to the POINT would be 1, 0.

How would one determine this in TSQL? My simple, not entirely accurate, approach was to make a linestring (POINT POINT) and extend out the X coord of one coords until the two linestrings intersected.

So:

1. linestring (0 0, 0.25 0) (no intersect)
2. linestring (0 0, 0.5 0) (no intersect)
3. linestring (0 0, 0.75 0) (no intersect)
4. linestring (0 0, 1 0) (intersection - so 1 0 is the point closest to POINT

This quasi worked, but doesn't seem to the most bestest/more performant way of accomplishing this.

For example, one inefficiency is that I move it one direction (positive increments), and if there was no match (after x attempts), then I would start over, but with negative increments.

To optimize, I tried moving in larger steps, then when intersected (probably went past the point), I backed off 1 increment and started from there with a smaller increment. I did this a couple of times - instead of going in tiny tiny increments so as not to overshoot by too much.

One acceptable assumption based on my processing that the POINT will be next to (left/right) of the LINESTRING.

Another acceptable assumption is that the LINESTRING will be fairly "perpendicular" to the POINT.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this mathematically rather than with a brute-force iterative algorithm.

There is a post to [get closest point to a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120357/get-closest-point-to-a-line) that describes the method.

I converted this method to SQL which returns the correct value (1,0).  Your 'trivial' example is actually a bit of an edge case (vertical line with infinite slope) so it seems robust.

I also tested the source code with this example: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iz07az84f5 and using the input for the line of (-1,2) (3,0) and  a point at (2,2) got the correct answer (1.4, 0.8).

SQL code (also in SQL Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d87aa/15)

```
DECLARE @x int, @y int, @x1 int, @y1 int, @x2 int, @y2 int 
DECLARE @atb2 float, @atp_dot_atb float
DECLARE @t float

--SELECT @x=0, @y=0 
--SELECT @x1=1, @y1=10, @x2=1, @y2=-10  
SELECT @x=2, @y=2
SELECT @x1=-1, @y1=2, @x2=3, @y2=0

SELECT @atb2 = SQUARE(@x2-@x1)  + SQUARE(@y2-@y1)  -- Basically finding the squared magnitude   of a_to_b
SELECT  @atp_dot_atb = (@x-@x1)*(@x2-@x1) + (@y-@y1)*(@y2-@y1) -- The dot product of a_to_p and a_to_b
SELECT @t = @atp_dot_atb / @atb2              --  The normalized "distance" from a to  your closest point

SELECT @x1 + (@x2-@x1)*@t, @y1 + (@y2-@y1)*@t  --Add the distance to A, moving towards B
```

Comment: Thanks - I figured there was more graceful way to do this. I converted the fiddle to real world lat/lon - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d87aa/23/0 - and I must have goofed something up in the conversion (long night, need (lots) more coffee :) ). The values don't seem to be on the line segments. (The SQLFiddle only outputs 1 row, but in MgmtStudio there are 7 rows)  @meisen99

Comment: I may not be able to look at this in the  next few hours; not sure why SQL Fiddle only outputs one row, I noticed that last night too when multiple SELECT statements are executed.  In terms of the point - the algorithm assumes that the line is infinite and the points provided are simply two points on that line.  There may need to be a test to see if the closest point is one of the two endpoints of the line.  Can you check to see if the point returned is on the (infinite) line defined by your coordinates?

Comment: I am using this for my string `declare @LineString GEOMETRY = Geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-74.7 21.8, -75.7 22.1, -77.8 22.6, -79.4 23.3, -80.4 24.5, -81.5 28, -84 33, -87 36)', 4326)` My breaks the line string into pairs (so -74.7 21.8, -75.7 22.1; and then -75.7 22.1, -77.8 22.6; etc).

Comment: Fixed it in your SQL Fiddler. Your late night & coffee meant you used "@lat" twice in the line calculating "atp_dot_atb": 
set @atp_dot_atb = (@lat-@x1)*(@x2-@x1) + (@lat-@y1)*(@y2-@y1)   Updated and the results look more sensible...